# Adding Environment Variables to the node process using CMD

Tags: node.js

I am trying to add the environment variables to the node process on start using CMD. I want achieve this without using the script in package.json & not using the dotenv package

I'm going through one of the node.js lectures & found the below command which will set the environment variables to the node process as below :

```
NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js
```

After some research I found that it is different for windows & as below :

```
SET NODE_ENV=development&&nodemon server.js
```

I tried the same in the cmd but got the error message NODE_ENV is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Just wanted to know how in CMD this adding environment variables works

Comment: Try run `set NODE_ENV=development` and then `echo %NODE_ENV%`

Comment: @Raz Luvaton Not working.